# Is it possible to get required roles for a specific Action?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5

I have a razor page in .NET 5 project that I'm working on. I'm using Role based Authentication and have several attributes set on either the Page or a specific action.

I want to display the required roles in the Access Denied page so the user knows that he/she must be a specific role to access the previous page.

Is it possible to get the authorization requirements for a specific action?

Right now I'm using the following authentication configuration. By default the redirect URL is passed to AccessDenied page.

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(o =>
{
  o.LoginPath = "/Login";
  o.AccessDeniedPath = "/AccessDenied";
});
```

This is the attributes I have on one of my pages.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RPH")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Management, Basic")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
}
```

What I would like to show in the AccessDenied page is something like:

> You must be an RPH and either Management or Basic roles to access this
> page

Comment: If I understood correctly you want to use attributes on action which is absolutely possible.

Comment: Yes I know that, I have attributes on actions. I want pull the roles or authorize attributes for a specific action.

Comment: Can you not pass specific roles for each action method through ViewData/ViewBag/etc. to your custom Access Denied page, and display that way there?

Comment: Could you please post related codes about how you redirect to the access denied page if the user doesn't have the enough role? Normally, we will add the redirect url. We could modify that method to get the attribute according to the url.

Comment: I added more information to my post.
As far as passing to the ViewBag/ViewData, I'm not sure that's possible as the authentication happens prior to the controller being called. Is there a middleware I can hook into to dynamically pass the required roles?

Comment: As far as  I know, the cookie authentication event's OnRedirectToAccessDenied method could fired when the role doesn't match, but it also doesn't contain the controller needed role information. Normally, the redirecr url will contains the return url as the querystring in the access denied path, you could use that path to get the required rule directly inside the access denied page.

Comment: I have the redirect path in the access denied page. Is there a at to get the required roles from the path or do I need to manually check and code a response for each path?

Comment: You should  manually check and code a response for each path. Since the returned context doesn't contains the reason why authorize failed.